# date range issue display in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to generate report from 01-Feb-2016 to 31-Mar-2016. Using formula

```
{cryRpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{product_details.date11} >= #" & 
DateTimePicker1.Text & "#  and {product_details.date11} <= #" & 
DateTimePicker2.Text & "#"}
```

but it is still not providing proper sequence, sometime places 01-Mar-2016 in between, same with 29-Feb-2016, using group in crystal report but still not success, help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between these `#` crystal treats as datetime and not date values to get correct values you need to convert to date try like this:

```
{cryRpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{product_details.date11} >=CDate( #" & 
DateTimePicker1.Text & "#) and {product_details.date11} <= CDate(#" & 
DateTimePicker2.Text & "#"})
```

I haven't checked the syntax, check when you are using in record selection formula